# How to connect a bitcoin node to a complete node through the local network?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I currently have a full bitcoin node on my local network and I would like to create another node but only update it by the local network.

I have tried with:

`./bitcoind -connect<iplocal>`

and

`./bitcoind -addnode<iplocal>`

but I get the following error

`` syntax error near unexpected token `newline' ``

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Juan, your question might recieve better answers in either https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour or https://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Juan,

It should be `./bitcoind -connect=<iplocal>` rather than `./bitcoind -connect<iplocal>` and you should be using `-connect` and not `-addnode` since the former will ensure that the node connects to only the host specified.